# How to make margin-top adjust with full-page background?

Tags: css

I am using the following code to achieve a full page background, regardless of window size.

CSS

```
 #header_logo {
   position: absolute;
   z-index: -999;
 }

 #header_logo img {
   min-height: 100%;
   min-width: 1024px;
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
 }

 @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
   #header_logo img {
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -512px !important;
   }
 }

 .main {
   background-color: #efefef;
   display: block;
 }
```

HTML

```
<div id="header-wrapper">
  <table class="header" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td id="header_logo" class="center middle"><img src="background_image.png">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div> 
<div class="main select-items">
...
</div>
```

However, the image has a logo in the center of it that shrinks/grows with the rest of the background and the logo becomes hidden behind a `div` that I have set-up in the page. If I set the `margin` of the `div` to allow enough space for the logo to appear on larger window sizes, it creates too much negative space on smaller window sizes. Is there a way to have the `margin-top` value adjust with the background image?

Notes:

1) Due to hosting/platform restrictions, I cannot use Javascript. I also cannot edit the HTML.
2)The site is a web portal for multiple companies, and based on log-in credentials, I can change which background will appear. However, I can only change a single `img` tag, which means the company's logo and background must be a single image file. Otherwise, I would simply add the logo as a separate image that is unaffected by the background change.

Comment: jsFiddle? markup? something?

Comment: @YotamOmer Is the code I included above not sufficient? What else should I add? Thanks!

Comment: I'd personally like to see the image and the div covering it..

Comment: agreed.  Markup is also important

Comment: What about `background-image: url('...')` in a div? You could use eg. `background-position: 50% 50%`, [background-size](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) etc.

Comment: @Stocki Thanks, but using that method wouldn't allow me to have a different background for each login.

Comment: Well, not the beautiest solution, but it is possible to use CSS StyleSheet + `<div style="background-image: url('...')"></div>`